# 400 Bad Request when trying to submit a POST request to upload artifacts in nexus

Tags: c#, .net, nexus

I am trying to upload artifacts using .net HttpClient but getting 400 Bad Request. I am giving a zip file in the request content. This is my code.

I was able to do this via the curl command and transformed the curl command to.net code.

curl -v -F r=release-folder -F hasPom=false -F g=release-group -F a=artifact-01 -F v=1.0 -F p=zip -F file=@P:\test.zip -u username:password https://localhost:80/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content --insecure

Please help pinpoint what I am doing wrong here.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();                        
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"),  
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nexusUrl"]))
    {
        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String 
        (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization",   
$"Basic   
    {base64authorization}");

    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent 
    (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["repository"]), "r");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("false"), "hasPom");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent 
    (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["group"]), "g");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("artifact-01), "a");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("1.0"), "v");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("zip"), "p");
    multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("zip"), "e");
    multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes
    (@"P:\test.zip")), "file", Path.GetFileName(@"P:\test.zip"));
    request.Content = multipartContent;

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync 
    (request);                   
    }                                
}
```

Comment: Any error message attached to the BadRequest response?

Comment: Hi, this is the error I get:
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2019 16:12:33 GMT
  Server: Nexus/2.14.12-02
  Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.6-SONATYPE-5348-V8
  Content-Length: 114
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
}}

Comment: So I fixed it myself. There was typo in the repository key in app settings.